# Suppression List in sendgrid

Tags: azure, sendgrid

Does SendGrid do a refresh of the suppression list based on any logic?

What we are looking at is if we have a list of users already in the suppression list due to some trivial issues like 
1) his/her mail box is full 
2) at the time of adding the mail ID to the suppression list the mail id is not created and after some time mail id got created.

Is there an option in sendgrid to clear all the mail from the suppression list in a periodic fashion say once in a week or on any pre configured time.

We are using Sendgrid from the Azure portal.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Bounce API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/bounces.html)? That will let you get your Bounce suppression list by a date range, and you can then program in cleanup/DELETE logic based on what you get back.